# How to get Selected Checkbox value by ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently my code works well with the input name, I can get the input value by input name
But I want my script to retrieve the input value with id input and not with name input?

here my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        getSelectedCheckBoxwithValueText("test")               
    });
    var getSelectedCheckBoxwithValueText = function (name1) {
        var data = $('input[name="' + name1 + '"]:checked');
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var resultdata='' ;
            data.each(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                 resultdata += $('label[for="cb-' + selectedValue + '"]').text() + "<br/>";

            });
            $("#divchecked").html(resultdata);
        }
        else {
            $("#divchecked").html("No Check box selected");
        }
        

    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    checked:
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="test" value="cricket" />
    <label for="cb-cricket">Cricket</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="test" value="swimming" />
    <label for="cb-swimming">Swimming</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="test" value="blog" />
    <label for="cb-blog">Blog</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="test" value="coding" />
    <label for="cb-coding">Coding</label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Selected checkbox:<br />
    <div id="divchecked"></div>
</body>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/showcode/L64nauo0/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var data = $('input[id=^"c"]:checked');
```

Only if the IDs not pseudos (so you really this IDs use), and do not use IDs thagt starts with c
This is a little hacker solution, but works!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but with this method you can't retrieve all input value, only one input value!

Comment: Okay I edit the post (with attribute front selector)

Comment: Thank you , I tried the solution with the 4 ids but it didn't work with me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `id` or `name` to select the checkboxes and/or their related labels. You can simplify your code like so

- Select all the checkboxes from the DOM and listen to `change` event on them.
- When the value of a checkbox changes, you get all selected checkboxes
  using [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- And then get the text of the related labels using [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $checkboxes.change(function () {
        let labels = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).next('label').text().trim();
        }).get();

        $("#divchecked").html(labels.join('<br />') || "No Check box selected");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
checked:
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="test" value="cricket" />
<label for="c1">Cricket</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="test" value="swimming" />
<label for="c2">Swimming</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="test" value="blog" />
<label for="c3">Blog</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="test" value="coding" />
<label for="c4">Coding</label>
<br/>
<br/>

Selected checkbox:<br />
<div id="divchecked"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need to fetch the inputs values, because my inputs values it's data fetch from a database